# Sum values inside foreach loop only if values are same

Tags: php, html

I have to check the condition i.e the user should not enter more than 24hrs / per day in the time sheet. Eg. (yyyy-mm-dd) 2014-12-21 | 5hrs , 2014-12-21 | 10hrs , 2014-12-21 | 10hrs then hit submit button , i need to sum up the hrs of the same day and should alert the user saying "Should not enter more than 24hrs a day".

Here is my Code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="" action="#" method="post">

   <?php for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
   <label>date</label>
   <input class="datefield" id="datefiled_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="date" name="datevalue[]" value="" / >
   <label>hrs</label>
   <input class="hrscheck" id="hrscheck_<?php echo $i; ?>" type="number" value="" name="hrs[]" />
   <br />

   <?php } ?>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
  </form>

  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $datevalue = $_POST['datevalue'];
    $prevDate = '';

   $hrs=0;

    foreach($datevalue as $key=>$values)
    {

         echo $curDate = ($values);
         echo "=>";
         echo $hrs = $_POST['hrs'][$key];
         echo "<br>";

       if ($curDate == $prevDate) {      
         echo $hrs +=$hrs;
       }       
        $prevDate = $curDate;
    }
  }

  ?>


 </body>
</html>
```

### OUTPUT

```
2014-12-25=>10
2014-12-25=>10
2014-12-25=>10

2014-12-26=>5
2014-12-26=>13
```

I have to sum 2014-12-25 having three hrs value (10+10+10) = 30 and alert user ( should not be more than 24hrs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build a summary array and then filter those with more than 30 hours reported for the same day:

```
// build summary array: [date] => array of time values
$summary = [];
foreach($datevalue as $key=>$values) {
     $summary[$values][] = $_POST['hrs'][$key];
}
// filter them
if (array_filter($summary, function($item) {
    return array_sum($item) > 24;
})) {
    echo "UH OH, a day doesn't have more than 24 hours";
}
```